# Can't get a correct type to expect a composed findUnique query with relations

Tags: typescript, prisma

Despite using the recommended way of getting Prisma types, I still get TS errors.

I have the following query:

```
await prisma.user.findUnique({
  where: {
    id: userId,
  },
  include: {
    currentStates: {
      include: {
        state: true,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

And I need to expected that exact type of result (with the relations), so I have the following props:

```
type InnerContextProps = {
  user: UserWithCurrentStates | null;
};
```

The definition of `UserWithCurrentStates` is:

```
type UserWithCurrentStates = Prisma.UserGetPayload<{
  include: {
    currentStates: {
      include: {
        state: true;
      };
    };
  };
}>;
```

But, I get a big TS error:

```
TS2322: Type 'Prisma__UserClient<({ currentStates: ({ state: { id: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; name: string; scope: string; }; } & { id: string; userId: string; stateId: string; happenedAt: Date; })[]; } & { ...; }) | null, null, DefaultArgs> | null' is not assignable to type '({ currentStates: ({ state: { id: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; name: string; scope: string; }; } & { id: string; userId: string; stateId: string; happenedAt: Date; })[]; } & { ...; }) | null'.
  Type 'Prisma__UserClient<({ currentStates: ({ state: { id: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; name: string; scope: string; }; } & { id: string; userId: string; stateId: string; happenedAt: Date; })[]; } & { ...; }) | null, null, DefaultArgs>' is not assignable to type '{ currentStates: ({ state: { id: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; name: string; scope: string; }; } & { id: string; userId: string; stateId: string; happenedAt: Date; })[]; } & { ...; }'.
    Type 'Prisma__UserClient<({ currentStates: ({ state: { id: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; name: string; scope: string; }; } & { id: string; userId: string; stateId: string; happenedAt: Date; })[]; } & { ...; }) | null, null, DefaultArgs>' is not assignable to type '{ currentStates: ({ state: { id: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; name: string; scope: string; }; } & { id: string; userId: string; stateId: string; happenedAt: Date; })[]; }'.
      Types of property 'currentStates' are incompatible.
        Type '<T extends User$currentStatesArgs<DefaultArgs> = {}>(args?: Subset<T, User$currentStatesArgs<DefaultArgs>> | undefined) => PrismaPromise<...>' is not assignable to type '({ state: { id: string; createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; name: string; scope: string; }; } & { id: string; userId: string; stateId: string; happenedAt: Date; })[]'.

context.ts(17, 3): The expected type comes from property 'user' which is declared here on type 'InnerContextProps'
```

I could not find any other way to get those types, but looks like they are no compatible. Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Prisma.validator](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/advanced-type-safety/operating-against-partial-structures-of-model-types#problem-using-variations-of-the-generated-model-type) API to create the type that has relation fields included. This should ideally fix the issue for you.

It could look something like this:

```
const UserWithState = Prisma.validator<Prisma.UserArgs>()({
  include: {
    currentStates: {
      include: {
        state: true,
      },
    },
  },
});

type UserWithStateType = Prisma.UserGetPayload<typeof UserWithState>
```

Comment: unfortunately, I get the very same error as my example :(

Comment: Can you share your schema file?

Comment: I found the issue, it was not related to Prisma nor TS. :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

At first, I upgraded to Prisma 4.12 and it was instantly fixed, then I rolled back to 4.11 and it was still working.

I could then reproduce the issue again by reinstalling all the packages of my pnpm turborepo, and turns out the issue was with my editor, Intellij IDEA. Something was not right so I had to delete the `.idea` folder and setup the project again.

After all, it was not related to Prisma, despite the misleading error.